# Pyramid Algorithm JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I was messing around with some basic algorithms. I wanted to know if someone has a shorter version of this one in JS to display the pyramid:

```
const total= 30;
let line = 1;

for (let i = 1; i < total; i = i + 2) {
    console.log(' '.repeat(total / 2 - line) + '*'.repeat(i))
    line++;
}
```

Comment: There isn't much you could do to optimize this, but you could remove either `line` or `i`, as both increase by a set amount each iteration. (Note that `i = line * 2 - 1`.) After that, there are some micro-optimizations, but usually the browser takes care of those.

Comment: There's a whole website for these kinds of questions - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com You might consider migrating it there for even more answers.

Answer (score 3):

that ?

```js
let s = '*'
for(let p=15;p--;) 
  {
  console.log( ' '.repeat(p) + s)
  s += '**'
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same using map function

```
function pyramid(height) {
  return Array(height).fill('*')
    .map((current, index) =>
      ' '.repeat(height - index) +
      current.repeat(index).split('').join(' ') +
      ' '.repeat(height - index))
    .join('\n');
}
console.log(pyramid(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

An even shorter approach by using a `while` statement.

This answer is highly inspired by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62451576/1447675) of [Mister Jojo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10669010/mister-jojo).

```js
let s = '*',
    p = 15;
    
while (p--) {
    console.log(' '.repeat(p) + s)
    s += '**';
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(Array.from({length:15},(_,i)=>"*".repeat(i*2+1).padStart(15+i)).join`\n`);
```